# How to display a new message each month for 20 consecutive months

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a solution to this problem. I'm writing a JavaScript to display one of 20 greetings each month for 20 consecutive months before the greetings start over. Below is the GreetingDetails Array:

```
    var GreetingDetails = [
    {// index0
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 0",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation0.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index0
    {// index1
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 1",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation1.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index1
    {// index2
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 2",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation2.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index2
    {// index3
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 3",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation3.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index3
    {// index4
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 4",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation4.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index4
    {// index5
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 5",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation5.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index5
    {// index6
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 6",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation6.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index6
    {// index7
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 7",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation7.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index7
    {// index8
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 8",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation8.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index8
    {// index9
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 9",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation9.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index9
    {// index10
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 10",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation10.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index10
    {// index11
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 11",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation11.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index11
    {// index12
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 12",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation12.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index12
    {// index13
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 13",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation13.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index13
    {// index14
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 14",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation14.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index14
    {// index15
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 15",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation15.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index15
    {// index16
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 16",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation16.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index16
    {// index17
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 17",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation17.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index17
    {// index18
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 18",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation18.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    }, // index18
    {// index19
        Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 19",
        Language: "Foreign Language",
        Translation: "English Translation",
        AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation19.mp3",
        CommerceLink: link
    } // index19
];
```

I've tried several different ways, testing to get each greeting, but continue to run into the problem of only getting 12. 12 since there are 12 months in a year and I'm checking the month for comparison in the for loop. I want to get this as dynamic as possible so no one has to touch again. Here is my most successful attempt doing date comparisons:

```
var m = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September','October', 'November', 'December'];

var y = [];
var d = new Date();
//var test = new Date(2020, 1, 1);

// This for loop adds the years to the y-array
for (var i = 0; i < addYears; i++) {
    y.push(startYear++);
}

//alert(m.length);
//alert(y.length);
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (d.getFullYear() === y[i]) {
        for (var j = 0; j < GreetingDetails.length; j++) {
            if (m[d.getMonth()] === m[j]) {
                GreetingBuilder = GreetingDetails[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

var GreetingBuilder;
GreetingElements = {
    topSection: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("section");
        holder.id = "required-greeting";
        return holder;
    },
    accessabilityP: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("p");
        holder.classList.add("visuallyhidden");
        holder.innerText = "The following is a greeting given in one of 20 foreign languages.";
        return holder;
    },
    greetingContainer: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("dl");
        holder.id = "language-greeting";
        return holder;
    },
    greetingDT: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("dt");
        holder.classList.add("greeting");
        return holder;
    },
    greetingLink: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("a")
        holder.href = GreetingBuilder.CommerceLink;
        holder.classList.add("language-link");
        holder.text = GreetingBuilder.Greeting;
        return holder;
    },
    audioContainer: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("dd");
        holder.classList.add("speaker");
        return holder;
    },
    audioPlayer: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("audio");
        holder.id = GreetingBuilder.Language.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
        holder.src = GreetingBuilder.AudioPath;
        holder.preload = "auto";
        return holder;
    },
    audioButton: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("button");
        holder.classList.add("pronunciation");
        holder.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById(GreetingElements.audioPlayer().id).play();
        };
        holder.innerText = "Listen to pronunciation";
        return holder;
    },
    languageNameDD: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("dd");
        holder.classList.add("language");
        holder.innerText = "(" + GreetingBuilder.Language + ")";
        return holder;
    },
    languageTranslationDD: function () {
        var holder = document.createElement("dd");
        holder.classList.add("translation");
        holder.innerText = '"' + GreetingBuilder.Translation + '"';
        return holder;
    },
    getFullGreetingSection: function () {
        var sectionInstance = this.topSection();
        var greetingDTInstance = this.greetingDT();
        var greetingContainerInstance = this.greetingContainer();
        var audioContainerInstance = this.audioContainer();


        greetingDTInstance.appendChild(this.greetingLink());
        greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(greetingDTInstance);

        audioContainerInstance.appendChild(this.audioPlayer());
        audioContainerInstance.appendChild(this.audioButton());

        greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(audioContainerInstance);
        greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(this.languageNameDD());
        greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(this.languageTranslationDD());

        sectionInstance.appendChild(this.accessabilityP());
        sectionInstance.appendChild(greetingContainerInstance);


        return sectionInstance;
    }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("back-to-top")[0].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', GreetingElements.getFullGreetingSection());
```

If you see something I've done wrong, please let me know. I'm sure there is a better way to go about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `(year * 12 + month) % 20`  is all you need to get the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me say thank you to all who replied. Your insight helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.

I found the answer in Nawed Khan's and Ferenc's reply. I figured some math with the years and months was needed, but couldn't think of the formula to use. I used the formula in Khan's monthDiff() method as I preferred it over breaking the formula into two pieces.

```
var diff = todayDate.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth() + (12 * (todayDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()));
```

Once done, as he did in his answer, I assigned the diff as the GreetingDetails index... GreetingDetails[diff] and viola, the magic happened. That worked great for a bit... until I got around to getting past 20 years, then I started getting the wrong greeting. The problem was in the while loop in Khan's response. So I changed it to subtract GreetingDetails.length (length of 20), and I got the correct greeting everytime.

```
while (diff >= GreetingDetails.length) {
    diff -= GreetingDetails.length;
}
```

This will also help later if the number of greetings in GreetingDetails[] changes. I needed this to be as dynamic as possible, so this should be the best way to make  it as such. In this way, only the greeting details would need to be changed and nothing else.

Although Khan and Ferenc were slightly off in there formula I'm up-voting them to give them credit as I used their replies to formulate the solution to my problem.

Full JS below:

```
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date(2020, 0)
    var diff = todayDate.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth() + (12 * (todayDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()));
    var link = "url";
    var GreetingBuilder;
    var GreetingDetails = [
        {// index0
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 0",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation0.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index0
        {// index1
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 1",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation1.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index1
        {// index2
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 2",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation2.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index2
        {// index3
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 3",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation3.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index3
        {// index4
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 4",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation4.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index4
        {// index5
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 5",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation5.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index5
        {// index6
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 6",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation6.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index6
        {// index7
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 7",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation7.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index7
        {// index8
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 8",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation8.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index8
        {// index9
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 9",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation9.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index9
        {// index10
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 10",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation10.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index10
        {// index11
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 11",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation11.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index11
        {// index12
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 12",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation12.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index12
        {// index13
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 13",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation13.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index13
        {// index14
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 14",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation14.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index14
        {// index15
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 15",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation15.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index15
        {// index16
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 16",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation16.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index16
        {// index17
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 17",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation17.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index17
        {// index18
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 18",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation18.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        }, // index18
        {// index19
            Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 19",
            Language: "Foreign Language",
            Translation: "English Translation",
            AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation19.mp3",
            CommerceLink: link
        } // index19
    ];

    while (diff >= GreetingDetails.length) {
        diff -= GreetingDetails.length;
    }

    GreetingElements = {
        topSection: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("section");
            holder.id = "required-greeting";
            return holder;
        },
        accessabilityP: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("p");
            holder.classList.add("visuallyhidden");
            holder.innerText = "The following is a greeting given in one of 20 foreign languages.";
            return holder;
        },
        greetingContainer: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("dl");
            holder.id = "language-greeting";
            return holder;
        },
        greetingDT: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("dt");
            holder.classList.add("greeting");
            return holder;
        },
        greetingLink: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("a")
            holder.href = GreetingBuilder.CommerceLink;
            holder.classList.add("language-link");
            holder.text = GreetingBuilder.Greeting;
            return holder;
        },
        audioContainer: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("dd");
            holder.classList.add("speaker");
            return holder;
        },
        audioPlayer: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("audio");
            holder.id = GreetingBuilder.Language.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
            holder.src = GreetingBuilder.AudioPath;
            holder.preload = "auto";
            return holder;
        },
        audioButton: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("button");
            holder.classList.add("pronunciation");
            holder.onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById(GreetingElements.audioPlayer().id).play();
            };
            holder.innerText = "Listen to pronunciation";
            return holder;
        },
        languageNameDD: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("dd");
            holder.classList.add("language");
            holder.innerText = "(" + GreetingBuilder.Language + ")";
            return holder;
        },
        languageTranslationDD: function () {
            var holder = document.createElement("dd");
            holder.classList.add("translation");
            holder.innerText = '"' + GreetingBuilder.Translation + '"';
            return holder;
        },
        getFullGreetingSection: function () {
            var sectionInstance = this.topSection();
            var greetingDTInstance = this.greetingDT();
            var greetingContainerInstance = this.greetingContainer();
            var audioContainerInstance = this.audioContainer();


            greetingDTInstance.appendChild(this.greetingLink());
            greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(greetingDTInstance);

            audioContainerInstance.appendChild(this.audioPlayer());
            audioContainerInstance.appendChild(this.audioButton());

            greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(audioContainerInstance);
            greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(this.languageNameDD());
            greetingContainerInstance.appendChild(this.languageTranslationDD());

            sectionInstance.appendChild(this.accessabilityP());
            sectionInstance.appendChild(greetingContainerInstance);


            return sectionInstance;
        }
    }

    GreetingBuilder = GreetingDetails[diff];

    document.getElementsByClassName("back-to-top")[0].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', GreetingElements.getFullGreetingSection());
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Designate a date in the past from which you can count the months. Then, take the months that have passed since then and mod it by the length of your greetings array.

Try adjusting "pastDate" to simulate the passage of time and get different greetings.

```js
var greetings = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19].map (x=> "Greeting #" + x);

var currentDate = new Date();
var pastDate = new Date("2018-10-01"); // pick arbitrary point in past as the "first" month

var differenceInYears = currentDate.getYear() - pastDate.getYear(); // 20 years ago

var index = differenceInYears * 12 + currentDate.getMonth() - pastDate.getMonth(); // how many months ago we "started" counting

console.log(greetings[index%greetings.length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var basedate = new Date(2020, 00);



function monthDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() +
    (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()))
}

function showmessage() {

  var curdate = new Date($('#curdate').val());
  var diff = monthDiff(basedate, curdate);
  
  
  while(diff > 19){
   diff = diff - 19;
  }

  $('#output').append('<div>Greeting: ' + GreetingDetails[diff].Greeting + '</div>');
}

var link = '';
var GreetingDetails = [{ // index0
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 0",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation0.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index0
  { // index1
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 1",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation1.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index1
  { // index2
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 2",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation2.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index2
  { // index3
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 3",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation3.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index3
  { // index4
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 4",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation4.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index4
  { // index5
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 5",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation5.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index5
  { // index6
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 6",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation6.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index6
  { // index7
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 7",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation7.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index7
  { // index8
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 8",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation8.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index8
  { // index9
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 9",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation9.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index9
  { // index10
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 10",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation10.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index10
  { // index11
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 11",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation11.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index11
  { // index12
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 12",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation12.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index12
  { // index13
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 13",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation13.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index13
  { // index14
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 14",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation14.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index14
  { // index15
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 15",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation15.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index15
  { // index16
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 16",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation16.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index16
  { // index17
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 17",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation17.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index17
  { // index18
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 18",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation18.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  }, // index18
  { // index19
    Greeting: "Foreign Greeting 19",
    Language: "Foreign Language",
    Translation: "English Translation",
    AudioPath: "/Content/Greetings/Pronunciation19.mp3",
    CommerceLink: link
  } // index19
];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='date' id="curdate" />
<button type="button" onclick='showmessage()'>Show</button>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

You need a base date to decide what month is 0.
Then you need the month difference between today's month and the base month.
If the diff is greater than 20, then subtract 20. I have used a while loop to keep subtracting 20s until the difference is no longer greater than 20.
Use the number as index of your greetings array `GreetingDetails[diff]`.

Here is a sample (ad working) code based on your greetings. You pick a date (as for current date in future).

Answer (score 0):

Only 12 months so only 12 unique values to work with but need 20?  Use the year!

```
2020 = 0
2021 = 1
```

So your 13th month would be in january 2021, or 12+1 and so on.

Take the current year and subtract 2020. Add this to the current month. Wrap the value between 0 and 19.